Live action TV-Show about kids/teenagers in a fantasy world
I'm looking for a fantasy TV show, that I saw some episodes of, when I was younger.
It was a live action show which featured teenagers(?) in a fantasy world. As far as I remember they were members of a "good" kingdom and had trouble with an "evil" group who wanted to take over the kingdom.
I've watched it some time between 1990-2008 on a German television channel meant for kids/teenagers (probably Kinderkanal/KiKa). I don't think it was a German production. The intro may have shown a few fantasy creatures. I checked out Spellbinder, but that doesn't seem to be it, as I don't recall any UFOs.
There is one episode I remember a bit better:
Some kind of curse was activated, that made all the good guys fall asleep for one day(?). The protagonists and some old druid/wizard were not affected. The bad guys tried to use that time to invade the good guys castle, so the protagonists did all they could, to delay their advance to the castle. They faked an ambush, and at some point the druid/mage created an illusion of a line of soldiers blocking the way. The bad guy soldiers where kind of afraid, so whenever something like that happened, they didn't want to go further for some time. In the end the bad guys still reached the castle, but the good guys woke up just in time to repel them.
I checked the list of all shows that aired on KiKa in the past, but nothing seems to fit. Spellbinder sounds like the closest, but when I checked it out, it didn't seem to be, what I was looking for.

Mystic Knights of Tir Na Nog S01E19, "Divide and Conquer," hits some of these plot points but not enough to suggest to me that it's the correct answer.

The way the knights fall asleep seems familiar. Maybe I am mixing up two different shows? I most definitely remember the illusion showing a row of soldiers blocking the bad guys advance.

Was this a children's television show (meant for a child/young adult audience), or were the characters simply teenagers?

It was meant for children/young adults, I edited the question.
